# iPhone 5s takes blurry photos only in apps that access camera

Tags: applications, iphone, camera

My iPhone 5s takes perfectly clear photos when I access and use the stock Camera app to take a photo. However, if I try to use the camera in an app, e.g. to use the camera in my banking app to deposit a check, the photo is too blurry to use. I have found this is the case with all apps that use camera other then the Camera app.

Comment: Your mention of check deposits makes me think that the focus may be affected by the proximity of the subject. (Holding the camera close) Have you tried tapping on the subject to sharpen focus?

Comment: Yes. Tried everything. You have to place the 4 corners of the check in a box  type template with the corners highlighted, so proximity isn't really up to the user; the photo is necessarily from whatever distance allow it to fit into the 4 corner template. It worked fine (check photo) for months and then one day just total blur.

Comment: That is frustrating!  Sorry to hear.  When was the last time you did a hard reset of the phone?  This does not affect your stored data.

Comment: I'm about to try that now. Never done it before. I was about to do it when a Music problem occurred on my Macbook, so now i'm using phone for music so have been putting it off! Problems abound!!

Comment: It only takes a couple of minutes.  Hold the Home and Power buttons down until you see the Apple logo come back.

Comment: ok I will try now

Comment: I tried to move to chat but I don't have permission...I did that and now I see an iTunes logo with an arrow below, pointing up to it, with a power cord pic below??Im plugged in to my Macbook's USB-C through adaptor to phone.

Comment: You did it while plugged in?  Unplug and try again.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: 10.2.1 currently

Comment: I'm running that on the new phone now though. I have a 6S plus… No problem at all. I think that there must've been an issue with the lense. I can't imagine what else could've caused it. I gave the phone to somebody else they are running the most updated version that the fiveS can run, I'm not sure if it's the same as mine or not, but they said they're fully updated instill the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, even when we have tried "everything," a reset of the device can help.  This 'reboots' the phone.

Hard Reset

- Hold the Home and Power buttons down at the same time until the  logo comes back to the screen. (The screen will go black, keep holding.)
- Let go of **BOTH** buttons when the logo comes back.  (Continuing to hold the Home button will put the iOS device into [Recovery Mode](http://www.imore.com/how-to-put-iphone-ipad-recovery-mode))

Recovery mode will re-download iOS and then give you the option of restoring from a backup.

If this doesn't work, and a restoration of the phone from scratch in Recovery Mode (which is time consuming for the download) doesn't work, if you iPhone is under warranty see if Apple will be able to help.  They want you to be happy and will do what they can within reason.

From a thread in [Apple support community](https://discussions.apple.com/message/11701200#11701200):

> Soft = Turn phone off and on.
>   Hard = BOTH buttons held until you see Apple Logo.
>
> Difference: I like to explain by thinking of a laptop. On a laptop (or
>   even computer) you can go to hibernation mode (memory gets written to
>   disk then powers down). When turned on, it loads back up from memory
>   and thus everything that was loaded in memory before shutting down is
>   put back. That is what a Soft reset is (when you do the power button
>   the slide to turn off). Thus if there was a memory leak for example in
>   some program causing issues (sluggish, crashes, etc)....then if you
>   just turn off and on, it will still have issues. A hard reset is like
>   pulling the plug on your computer. It will have to turn back on and
>   reboot fully. It does write an error log out to itself (nothing you
>   see) but causes no harm to your phone or data. It is just a way to do
>   a full clean boot up. This actually fixes about 90% of the issues most
>   people have.
>
> Has no effect on battery outside of the fact it has to boot up thus
>   processor and read writes will be happening.

Comment: Ya, so that is what I did....exactly that. Held both down until apple logo came back up. Then  at that point I let go of power and continued to hold down the home button (as described in earlier answer to do this hard reset) and this is what I am getting.

Comment: No!! Let go of both at the same time.  By continuing to hold the Home button you put it into restore mode.  Give me a few minutes to see if we can reverse that.

Comment: Just try it again, this time don't continue to hold the Home button.  It should just reset.

Comment: I got out of restore mode, did hard reset (sorry thought they were same thing). Unfortunately, no love....still total blur. How do I know if the reset "took"

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried going a DFU restore of the phone and setting up as new this should sort it.

Comment: Is that similar to Firmware?  No,I haven't and wouldn't know how to go about it. If you don't mind, please advise. Does this impact music or other photo files? Or use in general?

Comment: Just figured it out/ I will try this. I will LUK if it works. Thanks

Comment: DFU restore is full system wipe you do this by plugging into iTunes, backing up so if it doesn't work you can restore. Then hold home button and power button until phone turns off then only release the power button keeping th home button held until iTunes pops up saying its found a iPhone in recovery mode. Restore from there and don't restore from backup, so that looks like a new phone test the apps in question.  if this sorts it re-sync music and your photos should still be in your photo stream or photo library if you use photos in the cloud,

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This is less an answer to the question and more a comment on the question. Please use this area for canonical answers only. Questions about what have and haven't been tried should be left as comments on the question or, better, taken to a chat channel. I'll leave this stand for now to give you a chance to turn this in to a proper answer because I think you're on the right path here, but please bear this in mind in the future.